# Prove that there are infinitely many perfect cubes of the form $p^2+3q^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Prove that there are infinitely many perfect cubes of the form $p^2+3q^2$ where $p$ and $q$ are integers.

Hint: one approach is to set $p^2+3q^2=(a^2+3b^2)^3$ and then find $(p,q)$ in terms of $a,b$.

Any different approach is very welcome!

Comment: Hint: take any solution, multiply by a power of $6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this from cubing Eusenstein integers, of the form $a+b\sqrt{\;-3}$.

For $a, b$ as integers, then

$$(a+b\sqrt{-3})^3 = (a^3 - 9ab^2) + (3a^2b - 3b^3)\sqrt{-3} $$

Whereapon, one sees that $(a^2+3b^2)^3 = (a^3-9ab^2)^2 + 3(3a^2b-3b^3)^2$ directly follow.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the hint above, if $p^2 + 3q^2$ is a perfect cube, so is $(k^2)^3(p^2+3q^2)$ for any integer $k$.  But that is the same as $(pk^3)^2 + 3(qk^3)^2$.

All that remains is to show there is at least one solution, and $(0, \pm3)$ or $(\pm4, \pm4)$ or $(\pm14, \pm7)$ or $(\pm10, \pm9)$ are all solutions which are easily checked.

Comment: haha slick!     (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Using the hint that OP stated,

$$ \begin{array} { l l}
(a^2 + 3b^2 )^3 & = a^6 + 9 a^4 b^2 + 27a^2 b^4 + 27b^6 \\
& = (a^6 + 6 a^4 b^2 + 9 a^2 b^4) + 3( a^4 b^2 + 6a^2 b^4 + 9b^6 ) \\
& = (a^3 + 3ab^2)^2 + 3 (a^2b + 3b^3)^2 \end{array}$$